# netlogo move turtle nearest patch

Tags: netlogo

I want to move my turtle to the nearest red or green color patch in its vision.I tried this code but it doesnt move.What is wrong?

```
while [collectedDirt = 5]
[
  ask turtle 0 [ 
                   let nearest-patch min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = red or pcolor = green] in-cone 15 20)[distancemyself]
                   face nearest-patch
                   fd distance nearest-patch

               ]
  set collectedDirt collectedDirt + 1
  search-dirt ;; research whether there is red patch in-cone because of new position
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to provide us with a little bit more context, but my guess would be that you need something like `while [collectedDirt < 5]` instead of `while [collectedDirt = 5]`. If this block is the only way your turtles can "collect dirt", the code probably never even gets executed...

**Edit:**

You also might want to add a condition in case there is no red/green patch in the cone of vision:

```
if is-patch? nearest-patch [ 
  face nearest-patch
  fd distance nearest-patch
  set collectedDirt collectedDirt + 1
]
```

Comment: I tried it , too.But I get this error : FACE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
I am checking patches by search-dirt method to be sure to move , but sometimes it never works ,sometimes it stops suddenly :S

Comment: Also , search-dirt method :                                       to search-dirt
  let cnt count patches in-cone 15 20 with [pcolor = yellow or   pcolor = red ]
  if cnt < 1 
  [lt 10   
    search-dirt] 
end

Comment: Thank you better anymore :) Just I used ifelse instead of if to not stay stable in same position